# SQL Join query to return matching and non-matching record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a SQL Syntax to write a Join query.
I couldnt get the expected output, i request expert to help me.

```
Table: Table1

ScriptNumber    Date Filled    RefillsLeft
100               01/02/2014      1
200               01/03/2014      0
300               01/22/2014      3


Table : Table 2 

ScriptNumber    Date Filled    RefillsLeft
100               02/02/2014      0

Expected output

ScriptNumber    Date Filled    RefillsLeft
100               02/02/2014      0
300               null            null
```

SQL Statement

```
SELECT Table_2.ScriptNumber
       ,Table_2.DateFilled
       ,Table_2.RefillsLeft
    FROM Table_1
    LEFT JOIN Table_2
        ON Table_1.ScriptNumber = Table_2.ScriptNumber
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: i am not able to get the expected output. It is kind of full join. Thats my question

Comment: What have you tried so far? And can you explain your expected results in words? It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @goofyui That is not a question.

Comment: Left Join or Inner Join doesnt work to give this expected out

Comment: @goofyui add your SQL code

Comment: select Table_2.ScriptNumber,
Table_2.DateFilled,
Table_2.RefillsLeft from Table_1
left join Table_2
on Table_1.ScriptNumber = Table_2.ScriptNumber

Comment: Why are you not expecting `200` in your results. If you do `LEFT` join it will get all rows from `LEFT` table and only matching from `RIGHT` table. Can you also add what you getting as output right now.

Comment: 200 is not there in the Table2 and it has refillsleft = 0. I expect RefillsLeft is greater than 0.

Comment: @goofyui - Although I avoid books like these, I suggest that you at least read `sams - teach yourself sql in 10 mins by ben forta`. You should have figured out the code `where Table_1.RefillsLeft > 0` yourself. PS - Don't let your career be based on that book. But, its better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coming from including columns in `SELECT` statement from `table_2` that do not have values for rows that exists in `table_1`. You need to change `SELECT Table_2.ScriptNumber` to `SELECT Table_1.ScriptNumber`

As future reference make sure you always select all relevant columns from **LEFT** tables and only columns you need from **RIGHT** table. Otherwise you end up with less **NULL** rows instead of having data that is present in **LEFT** table.

Answer (score 1):

A left join could be useful here to get the records you want in Table_1 and any relevant details that *may* exist in Table_2

```
select Table_1.ScriptNumber
    , Table_2.DateFilled
    , Table_2.RefillsLeft
from Table_1
    left join Table_2 on Table_1.ScriptNumber = Table_2.ScriptNumber
where Table_1.RefillsLeft > 0
```

Such a description is helpful in your questions, too.

Comment: It returns the expected records. Thank you. Just incase, if i want to view the records which has only null value. How should i tune my query. Not using the where condition is equal to null